# NextJS not found page throws Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, custom-error-pages

I have this not found page: (Like on https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/environments/error-files)

```
import Button from "@/components/buttons/button";
import { useTranslations } from 'next-intl';
import Image from "next/image";

/**
 * 404 Error Page
 * @returns React Node
 */
export default async function NotFound() {
    // Get the translations
    const t = useTranslations('not-found');

    return (
        <div className="w-screen h-screen grid place-items-center">
            <div className="-translate-y-6">
                <Image
                    className="w-80"
                    src="/assets/images/cubes.svg"
                    width={559}
                    height={513}
                    alt={t('images.cubes')}
                />
                <h1 className="text-8xl w-[1000px] my-10">
                    {t('headings.not-found')}
                </h1>
                <Button onClick="/" background="yellow">
                    <h1 className="mt-1">{t('buttons.home')}</h1>
                </Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But i get the error "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, _payload, _init}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."
I verified i get the same error when i remove the translations and write plain text.
The weird thing is, if i remove my framer-motion animatepresence from my layout, i get the error "Error: Expected a suspended thenable. This is a bug in React. Please file an issue."

Comment: Should that be `const {t} = `

Comment: Is this in the app directory?

Comment: @Keith no, in next-intl it is const t =

Comment: @AmyBlankenship yes, app dir

Comment: A handy trick to debug -> if you wrap your `t` inside `JSON.stringify` what do you see?.  eg.  `alt={JSON.stringify(t('images.cubes'))}` and `{JSON.stringify(t('headings.not-found'))}`

Comment: @Keith the same thing
> I verified i get the same error when i remove the translations and write plain text.

Comment: `export default async function NotFound() `  Can you create `async` components in Next, in React as a component this will be a Promise, and a Promise is an object.   can you not just do -> `export default function NotFound() {`

Comment: I believe if you upgrade to the latest canary, you'll get a compile error telling you that error pages need to be client-side components. This may be part of your issue.